# Compare crafted item with offhand in Diablo 3 on consoles?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

When crafting new weapons for my Monk, which is currently dual-wielding (still levelling up), I can only compare the crafted item with my mainhand weapon.

Is there a way for me to switch and compare with the offhand weapon as well? Right now I have to exit the crafting system and enter the inventory to compare, and then go back into the crafting system.

I think I remember that I could hold Alt on PC to show the offhand item as well (or the second ring if I'm doing rings), but is this possible on the console version?

This is the Xbox One version, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try unequipping the weapons from both hands while crafting, then you could shuffle screens to Salvage while crafting.  I am not aware of a way to view details of any three items at once in D3 console.

This approach assumes your inventory is empty, except for the items you're newly crafting and the  existing equipment you want to compare.